# Find any file in directory/subdirectory and copy to new directory

Tags: batch-file, search, command, move, subdirectory

I have a directory with a number of folders that each include sub-folders. I want to run a batch that searches those folders for the existence of a specific sub-folder called "failed". If there is a file present in this sub-folder, I want it to then move that file to another defined folder.

I've tried to look up usage of "if exist" commands but can't seem to find anything that directly suits my needs.

The names and types of the files to be moved are random, which is why I believed the "if exist" to be the most utile.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @PA My directory structure is like this C:\FolderOne- FolderFifty > Backup, Failed. So each of the folders one through fifty will have two subdirectories called "Backup" and "Failed". I need to target only those "Failed" subdirectories and move whatever files exists there to another defined location. When I tried your suggestion the prompt returns "invalid syntax" Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read `help for` paying attention to the `/r` and `/d` options and then try this one-liner in the command line

```
for /d /r %a in (failed) do @echo %a
```

you will see that this loop iterates over all the directory structure and appends `failed` to the directory name

then add a check for the actual existence of the directory

```
if exist %a\nul @echo %a
```

then add a second loop to iterate over all of the contents of the found `failed` directory

```
for %b in (%a\*) do @echo %b
```

then replace the `echo` with the required `move` command

```
move %b %destination%\%~nxb
```

and there you go, with a simple single line

```
for /d /r %a in (failed) do @if exist %a\nul @for %b in (%a\*) do @move %b %destination%\%~nxb
```

or, translated into a bat file and spiced it up a bit

```
pushd %sourceroot%
for /d /r %%a in (failed) do (
  if exist %%a\nul (
    for %%b in (%%a\*) do (
      move %%b %destination%\%%~nxb
    )
  )
)
popd
```

you'll have to figure out a way to rename the destination file to avoid name clashes.